# Why do I get "Page does not exist" searching for people?

Tags: user-profile, people-search

I'm currently developing a SharePoint 2010 site but have come across an issue when searching people, as at present if I click to select people then search it takes me to an error page saying the page does not exist.

The User Profile Synchronization service is working and both FIM services are started and set to automatic on our primary farm server, which is where the UPS service runs. I've ran successful synchronizations and people can log into mysite and find it populated with their data from AD. The issue is when the crawler goes to do its work once complete the errors section displays the following information.

> 137 sps3://share1 
>   The object was not found. Local SharePoint sites 7/20/2010 4:30 PM

There is no other information avaliable from this. The name of the server running the UPS and FIM services is share1, I've tried the sps3 address as both FQDN and non FQDN with the same results. THe search account has read access to both the mysite and the primary content site as well as the UPS service.

Just to give you a better idea of our farm set up it consists of three servers:

- share1 - Primary content server
- share2 - Index server used to index
  search crawl results
- share3 - Farm SQL server

Comment: Resolved the issue partly, in that we can now crawl the user profiles.

We were able to do this by changing the sps3 address from that of the server to the address of the mysite.

So sps3://dev_shp1 became sps3://mysite-portal

Sounds simple but had us stumped for a bit, although still having the issue of when performing a people search the page it goes to does not display and instead shows the standard IE page does not exist. If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this link](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157%2D7d96%2D4e15%2Da987%2D54b8a3e4d948&ID=53) which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by following [this link](http://sharepoint2010blog.blogspot.com/2010/01/error-in-crawling-user-profiles-in.html).

After following the previous link you might get an access denied error, follow [this link](http://svengillis.blogspot.com/2008/10/access-denied-when-crawling-moss.html) to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the proxy settings were responsible for the error.  Try setting your proxy to "Do not connect by using a proxy server" in the search service application system status screen.